# Try-Catch within Using()

Tags: c#

My code is currently

```
using(var driver = new driver()){something}
```

And I want to be able to catch exceptions. However I only want to catch exceptions thrown by "driver = new driver". Looking online I can find how to catch exceptions thrown by the whole thing or by "something" but I cannot work out how to put a try-catch into the "using" parameter.

Comment: Don't use `using`. Do it yourself

Comment: The using is mainly used to enforce disposed to be called on the object. It does not affect your try catch implementation.

Comment: @Backs I need to use using since "driver = new driver" opens a new window that needs to close once the process is complete (at the end of the "using")

Comment: The code should be something like `using(var driver = new Driver()){something}` - the scope of `driver` is probably relevant (not externally visible).

Comment: @Kobi This is just an example. I just wanted to make it easy to understand

Comment: The frameworks garbage collection will deal with that. Unless you're opening a resource like a database connection or memory streams your object reference will be marked for collection once it loses reference.

Comment: "I need to use using since "driver = new driver" opens a new window" - could I suggest changing that design? It's pretty odd for a constructor call to open a new window, IMO.

Comment: How about `using(var driver = CreateDriver())` and put a try/catch inside your `CreateDriver` method.

Comment: You'd have to do a try catch outside and then an if check after the fact. So `try var driver = new driver catch` etc. then `if ( driver == true condition ) something`

Comment: @JonSkeet That just how the package works. Not much I can do about it.

Comment: @Joe - That's an answer.

Comment: @Kobi, OK I'll add as an answer

Answer (score 5):

It's a very strange requirement, but whatever that's your call.

You should get rid of the `using` completely, and handle the dispose yourself (which has the same result).

This is what you want:

```
driver driver = null;

try
{
    try
    {
        driver = new driver();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // Here is your specific exception.
    }

    // Do something
}
finally
{
    if(driver != null)
        driver.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just do it:

```
Driver driver = null;

try
{
    driver = new Driver();
}
catch()
{
    // do whatever, throw, fail, return...
}

// if you did not break out of your logic in the catch (why not?)
// add an if(driver != null) before you proceed

using(driver)
{
    // something
}
```

Comment: You should ensure `driver`is not `null` in your `using`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Correct, I assumed that the catch() would be fatal, as in another throw, return or something...

Comment: "Using" is used to enforce dispose, will 'driver' be disposed after using? or we are using it in wrong way?

Comment: @Lali I don't really get what you are asking... yes, this is what `using` was made for. It enforces that the driver instance will be disposed.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a method to construct your driver and put your try/catch in there:

```
private static Driver CreateDriver()
{
    try
    {
        return new Driver();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // whatever other exception handling you want
        return null;
    }
}    

using(var driver = CreateDriver())
{
    // something
}
```

Of course, if you do this, when your `something` code is executing inside the `using` block, `driver` may be null, so you'll need to check for this, e.g.:

```
using(var driver = CreateDriver())
{
    if (driver != null)
    {
        // something
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The "using" clause, primarily function is to dispose managed code resources once the process inside the clause has been completed. It "hides" a try catch block inside it, but if you really want to handle errors, you need to do it yourself.

eg.

```
Try
{
  //do stuff
}
catch (exception ex)
{
  //handle exception
  //resource.Dispose();
}
```

After you handle your exceptions, you should dispose the unused resources by calling `.Dispose()`, assuming that the latter is a managed code resource and encapsulates the `IDisposable` interface

Comment: "It "hides" a try catch block inside it" Actually it "hides" a try/finally-block.

Comment: Yes...I accidentally typed catch...sorry

Comment: Using `Dispose()` manually is not a good approach. You can use using inside `try/catch`, because it will create `try/finally` inside...

Comment: True,  never encouraged it, just trying to give an example, that managed code resources need to be disposed manually, based on the question asked, when exceptions need to be handled explicitly, if the using clause is not implemented. But then you have nesting. If it is ok by the developer at the given time, then its fine by me :)